# Forgot password is not sending email verification (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have a password retriever function. But the problem is, the verification is not sending on my email or whatsoever. My goal is to reset my password using gmail authentication. just like how you can reset your password on social medias. I have provided my codes below. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

**Views:**

```
<h2>Reset</h2>
<div id="resest_password_form">
    <form action="/page/reset_password" method="POST">
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email');?>" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reset" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <?php 
    echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');
    if(isset($error)){
        echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
    ?>  

</div>
```

**Controllers:**

```
//reset_password email checker validation is working
      public function reset_password(){
          if(isset($_POST['email'])&& !empty($_POST['email'])){
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email_Address', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[50]|valid_email|xss_clean');
                
                if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                   
                    $this->load->view('view_reset_password', array('error' => 'Please'));
                  
                }else {
                    $email = trim($this->input->post('email'));
                    $result = $this->pages->email_exists($email);
                    
                    if($result){
                        
                        $this->send_reset_password_email($email, $result);
                      
                        $this->load->view('vw_register', array('email' => $email));
                }else {
                      $this->load->view('page/view_reset_password', array('error' => 'Please else'));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $this->load->view('page/view_reset_password');
            }
        }
        
        //sending email_verification is not working. I'm not receiving any reset link to my gmail.
        private  function send_reset_password_email($email, $firstname) {
            


$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'd****@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'd*****',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 

           


            $this->load->library('email');
            $email_code = md5($this->config->item('salt') . $firstname);
            
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
            $this->email->from($this->config->item('bot_email'), 'Freight Forum');
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Please');
            
            
            $message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
                        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html>
                        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                        </head><body>';
            
            $message .= '<p> Dear' . $firstname .',</p>';
            
            $message .= '<p>WE<strong><a href="' . base_url(). 'page/reset_password_form'.$email .'/'.$email_code .'">click here</a></strong> to reset</p>';
            $message .= '<p>Thanks</p>';
            $message .= '<p>The Team</p>';
            $message .= '</body></html>';
            
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();
            
    }
```

Model:

```
//working
    public function email_exists($email){
            $sql = "SELECT firstname, email FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);
            $row = $result->row();
            
            return ($result->num_rows() === 1 && $row->email) ? $row->firstname : false;
        }
```

Comment: Additionally, I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOZQ-C176Mw&t=591s&ab_channel=WinterwindInc.

Comment: smtp configuration missing see ref link https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-email-codeigniter-smtp/

Comment: I added smtp configuration. Please, see the updated codes above. Thank you. I added these: https://prnt.sc/zyg492

Comment: if ($this->email->send ()) {
  echo "Success";
  } else {
   
    print_r ( $this->email->print_debugger () );
   
   exit ();
  }
print error message

Comment: This is the error i caught: https://prnt.sc/zyosh1 "your server might not be configured to send mail using this method"

Comment: SMTP enable or not? because by default not enable.

Comment: Is this enabled? I'm sorry, i'm really new to this. This is what happened so far: https://prnt.sc/zywrnd

Comment: https://support.cloudways.com/configure-gmail-smtp/ refer link for gmail smtp

Comment: I'm currently setting up a cloudway account. I will update you once i am done. Thank you very much.